# Translate 3D pick into texture projection?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to write a very small tool in WebGL that allows me to paint into UV'ed meshes. One of the challenges, so far, is trying to find a way to translate the mouse pick position into the position i should paint in the loaded texture. Does anyone have any example or can recommend some literature on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "trick" you're looking for is probably **THREE.Raycaster.setFromCamera()**.  [Here's a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uh19Lh0d/) that does a simple version of what I think you're trying to do.  It renders a simple scene containing a textured sphere in one canvas and puts a copy of the texture applied to the sphere in another canvas.  Clicking on the sphere will draw a red dot on corresponding spot on the texture in the second canvas.

The interesting points are:

In **init()** we define a click hander for rendering canvas, called **clickCanvas**.  It passes the x and y coordinates of the click event to **getClickPosition()**:

```
function getClickPosition(n, x, y) {
        var rect;

        rect = n.getBoundingClientRect();
        return([
                (x - rect.left) / n.clientWidth,
                (y - rect.top) / n.clientHeight
        ]);
}
```

This translates the x and y coordinates to an UV-ish ordered pair of values between 0 and 1.  These values are passed to **projectLocation()**:

```
function projectLocation(x, y) {
        var c, i, v, p;

        // Bounds check our coords
        if(x < 0) x = 0;
        if(x > 1) x = 1;
        if(y < 0) y = 0;
        if(y > 1) y = 1;

        // Convert our values from the range [0, 1] to the range [-1, 1]
        v = new THREE.Vector2();
        v.x = x * 2 - 1;
        v.y = (-y * 2) + 1;

        raycaster.setFromCamera(v, camera);
        i = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);
        if(i.length > 0) {
                getLocation(i[0]);
        }
}
```

This takes the UV-ish coordinates and converts them into values between -1 and 1, which is what the THREE.Raycaster() wants (in this example it would be cleaner to have **getClickPosition()** do this automagically, but in real-world code you might might want the relative position of the click in the DOM element).  The raycaster figures out if there's anything intersecting a ray projected from the where the click occurred (on the "camera lens") into the scene.  From there the intersection object (if any) is passed to **getLocation()**:

```
function getLocation(intersect) {
        var uv;

        uv = intersect.uv;
        x = Math.round(uv.x * texture.image.width);
        y = Math.round((1 - uv.y) * texture.image.height);

        canvasCtx.lineWidth = 1;
        canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'red';
        canvasCtx.fillRect(x - 1, y - 1, 2, 2);
        canvasCtx.fill();
}
```

The intersection object contains the UV coordinates of the point of intersection.  **getLocation()** translates these into XY coordinates in the texture.